# Laravel, очистка кэша пагинации

Tags: laravel, кэширование

На сайте используется кэш драйвер `default`. Допустим пагинация кэшируется примерно так:
**App\Http\Controllers\ProductController**

```
$currentPage = request()->get('page',1);

$category = Cache::remember('products.' . $currentPage, 10, function(){
    return Product::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->where(['derc' => 1,'elaninnovu' => 'Satılır'])->paginate(10);
});
```

Подскажите, если в админке редактировать или удалять модель `Product`, как правильно очищать кэш?
Ещё нужно учесть что кэшируются не только продукты, но и другие модели и дополнительные данные, у которых название кэша различается.
А также продукты могут кэшироваться как отношение в модели `Category::with('products')`.
т.е. суть проблемы в том, что нужно или удалять определённые кэши с определёнными названиями, или удалять сразу весь кэш.

**app\Models\Product**

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted(function(Model $model) {
        $name = 'products.somecachename';
        Cache::forget($name);
        Cache::rememberForever($name, function () {
            return Product::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->where(['derc' => 1,'elaninnovu' => 'Satılır'])->paginate(10);
        });
    });
}
```

Правильным ли будет решение если при сохранении в кэше данных, допустим модели `Product`, записывать отдельно в кэш все созданные названия кэша?

**App\Providers\EventServiceProvider**

```
public function boot(): void
{
    parent::boot();

    Event::listen(function (\Illuminate\Cache\Events\KeyWritten $event) {
        if ($event->key == 'allCache') return;

        $allCache = cache('allCache') ?? [];
        if (!in_array($event->key, $allCache)) {
            $allCache[] = $event->key;
            cache(['allCache' => $allCache]);
        }
    });
}
```

а потом очищать кэш:
**app\Models\Product**

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted(function(Model $model) {

        $allCache = cache('allCache') ?? [];
        foreach ($allCache as $cache) {
            cache()->forget($cache);
        }
        
    });
}
```

Comment: Можно их не записывать. Или по крайней мере не таким способом. В чём проблема использовать теги?  Когда вы кешируете какие-то результаты, вы помечаете их тегами. Например, я кеширую Model::with('products') и ставлю тег 'with_products', когда просто вывожу данные на страницу, то тег 'products' и так далее в других местах. Названия мне всегда известны. И при удалении продукта я делаю так:  Cache::tags(['products', 'with_products'])->flush() другими словами я удаляю кеш списка продуктов, так как он изменился и удаляю кеш всех кто использует мои продукты в своих выводах

Comment: @Dmitrii Sedov теги же для драйвера file не работают, только для array

Comment: _Правильным ли будет решение если при сохранении в кэше данных, допустим модели Product, записывать отдельно в кэш все созданные названия кэша?_ - выбор особо не велик, либо хранить где-то ключи по которым удалять, либо втупую смотреть через Cache::has()